# split string at different types of characters into separate strings

Tags: c

Is there a way to split a string at different types of characters into separate strings?

```
char str[] ="(I) 44like22 .cookies. ,This, /is\ ?tricky?";
```

Something like this?

```
( I ) 44 like 22 . cookies . , This , / is \ ? tricky ?
```

Olaf This.

```
char *a;
char *strings[100] = {0};
int k = 0;
a = strtok (line_storage," ");
k = 0;
while (a != NULL)
{
    strings[k] = malloc(strlen(a)+1);
    strcpy(strings[l], a);
    a = strtok (NULL," ");
    k++;
}
```

Modified Jonathan Leffler but not very well. I'm trying to figure out a way to make where I can reuse it every time I run `fgets` on each line of a file.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char  str[] = "(I) 44like22 .cookies. ,This, /is\\ ?tricky?";
    char *s = (char *)str;
    char  str1[] = "(I) 44like22 .cookies. ,This, /is\\ ?tricky? 1122Keep.. (giving) 13me09 %more% 1magic1";

    char   out[2 * sizeof(str)];
    char  *ptr[sizeof(str)];
    char **p = ptr;
    char  *o = out;
    int    n = 0;
    int    i = 0;


    int c = 0;


    printf("Whole string: <<%s>>\n", str);

    while ((c = (unsigned char)*s++) != '\0')
    {
        if (isdigit(c))
        {
            *p++ = o;
            *o++ = c;
            while (isdigit((unsigned char)*s))
                *o++ = *s++;
            *o++ = '\0';
            n++;
        }
        else if (isalpha(c))
        {
            *p++ = o;
            *o++ = c;
            while (isalpha((unsigned char)*s))
                *o++ = *s++;
            *o++ = '\0';
            n++;
        }
        else if (ispunct(c))
        {
            printf("o is %d \n", *o);
            printf("c is %d \n", c);
            *p++ = o;
            *o++ = c;
            while (ispunct((unsigned char)*s))
                *o++ = *s++;
            *o++ = '\0';
            n++;
        }
        else if (!isspace(c))
        {
            printf("Hmmm: don't know how to classify %d (%c)\n", c, c);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Fragment[%2d] = %s\n", i, ptr[i]);
    }

    free(p);
    free(o);
    //free(out);
    //free(ptr);

    s = str1;
    out[2 * sizeof(str1)];
    *ptr[sizeof(str1)];
    **p = (char **)ptr;
    *o = out;
    n = 0;
    i = 0;

    printf("Whole string: <<%s>>\n", str);

    while ((c = (unsigned char)*s++) != '\0')
    {
        if (isdigit(c))
        {
            *p++ = o;
            *o++ = c;
            while (isdigit((unsigned char)*s))
                *o++ = *s++;
            *o++ = '\0';
            n++;
        }
        else if (isalpha(c))
        {
            *p++ = o;
            *o++ = c;
            while (isalpha((unsigned char)*s))
                *o++ = *s++;
            *o++ = '\0';
            n++;
        }
        else if (ispunct(c))
        {
            printf("o is %d \n", *o);
            printf("c is %d \n", c);
            *p++ = o;
            *o++ = c;
            while (ispunct((unsigned char)*s))
                *o++ = *s++;
            *o++ = '\0';
            n++;
        }
        else if (!isspace(c))
        {
            printf("Hmmm: don't know how to classify %d (%c)\n", c, c);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

New tweak. I wanted to make a small tweak to separate `"]"` and `")"` from `";"`. So like this `"];"` into `"]"` `";"` and ");" into `")"` `";"`.

```
for(x = 0; x < n; x++)
{
    printf("ptr[x] is %s \n", ptr[x]);
    cmp_str3 = strcmp(ptr[x], "];");
    cmp_str4 = strcmp(ptr[x], ");");
    if(cmp_str3 == 0)
    {
        printf("Match1 \n");
        strcpy(str1, ptr[x]);
        printf("Match2 \n");
        ptr[x][1] = '\0';
        printf("Match3 \n");
        //printf("ptr[x+1] %c %d \n", ptr[x+1], ptr[x+1]);
        //printf("ptr[x+1][0] %c %d \n", ptr[x+1][0], ptr[x+1][0]);
        ptr[x+1] = malloc(strlen("foo") + 1);
        ptr[x+1][0] = str1[1];
        printf("Match4 \n");
        ptr[x+1][1] = '\0';
        printf("Match5 \n");
        n++;
    }
    if(cmp_str4 == 0)
    {
    }
}
cmp_str3 = 0;
cmp_str4 = 0;
memset(str1, 0, 15);
memset(str2, 0, 15);
```

Comment: There is. What have you done yourself to find out? Sorry, this is no code-writing service.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. You should show us what you've tried, because it will show us something of what you expect. How are you allocating the pointers for the substrings? How are you allocating the space to copy the characters into? Are you familiar with `malloc()`? Are you just printing the units separately? Have you looked at `<ctype.h>`. Beware `strtok()`; it isn't what you need. Indeed, it isn't entirely clear what's the best approach to the problem, mainly because you've not shown or stated (but shown is better) what you want.  But it _is_ doable.

Comment: The only way I can think of strtok. strtok unfortunately throws away whatever it sees that matches.

Comment: Try [`strspn`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strspn.3.html) or its negated version `strcspn`. Which one to use depends on whether you want a split on allowed characters vs. disallowed characters. Despite your example, your question is not exaclty clear on it.

Comment: Or you could parse the string char by char comparing (the category of) each with the previous one.

Comment: @Olaf what you see above.

Comment: As I already told you, you can't use `strtok()` — because it zaps what it finds as a delimiter, and you need to know what is the delimiter.  Are your character classes letters, digits, punctuation, spaces?  Using `strspn()` has problems with creating the lists of characters in each class.  Using `isalpha()`, `isdigit()`, `ispunct()`, `isspace()` seems better, but it is hard to avoid repetition.  Incidentally, the source string needs to use ```\\``` in place of a single backslash.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler what I have tried is now posted. I showed you what I expected with `( I ) 44 like 22 . cookies . , This , / is \ ? tricky ?`. I'm making an array of strings (not sure what the technical name is). Yes I am familiar with malloc(). No I want to store them. Thank you for pointing out <ctype.h>. strtok() is my issue. I know it will throw away what I want. I want to turn `char str[] ="(I) 44like22 .cookies. ,This, /is\ ?tricky?";` into `( I ) 44 like 22 . cookies . , This , / is \ ? tricky ?`. Not sure how to make that clearer.

Comment: @Jongware how would strspn help me? I don't see how the length of the prefix substring is important. I am trying to break `char str[] ="(I) 44like22 .cookies. ,This, /is\ ?tricky?";` into separate pieces like you see here `( I ) 44 like 22 . cookies . , This , / is \ ? tricky ?`.

Comment: I think I understand your problem. You cannot use `strtok()` sensibly. You've not yet allocated space for your `strings` pointers to point at, because you're going to have to copy the data from the source `str` into the output because you need to be able to add a null byte after any character _without_ overwriting what follows in the original string. So, you can take the cautious approach and allocate `2 * sizeof(str)` bytes as an array of characters where the characters from `str` will be copied, possibly with a null byte after each one. Or you can do something else fancy — I'm not sure what.

Comment: `strspn()` has similar problems to `strtok()`; both require you to define lists of characters that a relevant or irrelevant.  Neither is appropriate as part of the solution for this problem.  (You could do enough preprocessing to make `strspn()` usable; I'm not convinced it is worth it, though.  The embargo on `strtok()` is close to absolute; you'd have to have a copy of the string for it to hack, and then you'd have to play some funny games to know what it zapped with a null byte, and restore that, etc.  Absolutely brutally unpleasant.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler can you recommend a way to do this please?

Comment: Is "different types of characters"  meant alphabets, numbers and others? or More fine? E.g (((abc.?))) => ((( abc .?))) or ( ( ( abc . ? ) ) ) etc.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yes alphabets, numbers and others. Your first example (((abc.?))) => ((( abc .?))).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely happy with this code, but it is relatively clean and seems to do the job.

#### `splitit.c`

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char  str[] = "(I) 44like22 .cookies. ,This, /is\\ ?tricky?";
    const char *s = str;

    char   out[2 * sizeof(str)];
    char  *ptr[sizeof(str)];
    char **p = ptr;
    char  *o = out;
    int    n = 0;

    /* ( I ) 44 like 22 . cookies . , This , / is \ ? tricky ? */

    int c;

    printf("Whole string: <<%s>>\n", str);

    while ((c = (unsigned char)*s++) != '\0')
    {
        if (isdigit(c))
        {
            *p++ = o;
            *o++ = c;
            while (isdigit((unsigned char)*s))
                *o++ = *s++;
            *o++ = '\0';
            n++;
        }
        else if (isalpha(c))
        {
            *p++ = o;
            *o++ = c;
            while (isalpha((unsigned char)*s))
                *o++ = *s++;
            *o++ = '\0';
            n++;
        }
        else if (ispunct(c))
        {
            *p++ = o;
            *o++ = c;
            while (ispunct((unsigned char)*s))
                *o++ = *s++;
            *o++ = '\0';
            n++;
        }
        else if (!isspace(c))
        {
            printf("Hmmm: don't know how to classify %d (%c)\n", c, c);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("Fragment[%2d] = %s\n", i, ptr[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation (GCC 5.1.0 on Mac OS X 10.10.5):

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
      -Wold-style-definition -Werror splitit.c -o splitit
```

Sample run:

```
Whole string: <<(I) 44like22 .cookies. ,This, /is\ ?tricky?>>
Fragment[ 0] = (
Fragment[ 1] = I
Fragment[ 2] = )
Fragment[ 3] = 44
Fragment[ 4] = like
Fragment[ 5] = 22
Fragment[ 6] = .
Fragment[ 7] = cookies
Fragment[ 8] = .
Fragment[ 9] = ,
Fragment[10] = This
Fragment[11] = ,
Fragment[12] = /
Fragment[13] = is
Fragment[14] = \
Fragment[15] = ?
Fragment[16] = tricky
Fragment[17] = ?
```

I observe that there are no multi-punctuation sequences in the sample data; however, the code is symmetric so it will handle them OK.

I'm not happy with the code because of the repetition in the `if` statements, but the amount of control data to be manipulated makes writing a function messy.

You can argue about the variable names too; I'll accept that they're on the overly-terse side of 'brief but meaningful'.

---

#### Avoiding repetition

This code uses function pointers to avoid repetition.  Using pointers to functions is powerful, but not necessarily something you're ready to handle.  It does allow me to avoid using a separate function with half a dozen or so parameters.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char  str[] = "(I) 44like22 .cookies. ,This, /is\\ ?tricky?"
        "\nBut (as he said, \"Isn't it delicous fun!\"), he vanished.";
    const char *s = str;

    char   out[2 * sizeof(str)];
    char  *ptr[sizeof(str)];
    char **p = ptr;
    char  *o = out;
    int    n = 0;
    int    c;

    printf("Whole string: <<%s>>\n", str);

    while ((c = (unsigned char)*s++) != '\0')
    {
        int (*ctype)(int c) = 0;
        if (isdigit(c))
            ctype = isdigit;
        else if (isalpha(c))
            ctype = isalpha;
        else if (ispunct(c))
            ctype = ispunct;
        else if (isspace(c))
            continue;
        else
        {
            printf("Hmmm: don't know how to classify %d (%c)\n", c, c);
            continue;
        }
        *p++ = o;
        *o++ = c;
        while ((*ctype)((unsigned char)*s))
            *o++ = *s++;
        *o++ = '\0';
        n++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("Fragment[%2d] = %s\n", i, ptr[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Whole string: <<(I) 44like22 .cookies. ,This, /is\ ?tricky?
But (as he said, "Isn't it delicous fun!"), he vanished.>>
Fragment[ 0] = (
Fragment[ 1] = I
Fragment[ 2] = )
Fragment[ 3] = 44
Fragment[ 4] = like
Fragment[ 5] = 22
Fragment[ 6] = .
Fragment[ 7] = cookies
Fragment[ 8] = .
Fragment[ 9] = ,
Fragment[10] = This
Fragment[11] = ,
Fragment[12] = /
Fragment[13] = is
Fragment[14] = \
Fragment[15] = ?
Fragment[16] = tricky
Fragment[17] = ?
Fragment[18] = But
Fragment[19] = (
Fragment[20] = as
Fragment[21] = he
Fragment[22] = said
Fragment[23] = ,
Fragment[24] = "
Fragment[25] = Isn
Fragment[26] = '
Fragment[27] = t
Fragment[28] = it
Fragment[29] = delicous
Fragment[30] = fun
Fragment[31] = !"),
Fragment[32] = he
Fragment[33] = vanished
Fragment[34] = .
```

#### Working with `fgets()`

The key thing is to work out where the boundaries are between the code that just happens to set the string to a value and the code that works reasonably generically, and separate the more generic code into a function which is called from the `main()` function.  I've adapted the more repetitive code for the purpose:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

 static void split_string(const char *buffer, size_t buflen)
 {
    const char *s = buffer;
    char   out[2 * buflen];
    char  *ptr[buflen];
    char **p = ptr;
    char  *o = out;
    int    n = 0;
    int c;

    printf("Whole string: <<%s>>\n", buffer);

    while ((c = (unsigned char)*s++) != '\0')
    {
        if (isdigit(c))
        {
            *p++ = o;
            *o++ = c;
            while (isdigit((unsigned char)*s))
                *o++ = *s++;
            *o++ = '\0';
            n++;
        }
        else if (isalpha(c))
        {
            *p++ = o;
            *o++ = c;
            while (isalpha((unsigned char)*s))
                *o++ = *s++;
            *o++ = '\0';
            n++;
        }
        else if (ispunct(c))
        {
            *p++ = o;
            *o++ = c;
            while (ispunct((unsigned char)*s))
                *o++ = *s++;
            *o++ = '\0';
            n++;
        }
        else if (!isspace(c))
        {
            printf("Hmmm: don't know how to classify %d (%c)\n", c, c);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("Fragment[%2d] = %s\n", i, ptr[i]);
}

int main(void)
{
    const char  str[] = "(I) 44like22 .cookies. ,This, /is\\ ?tricky?";
    split_string(str, sizeof(str));

    char buffer[4096];
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != 0)
        split_string(buffer, strlen(buffer)+1);

    return 0;
}
```

There are four changes up to and including the first `printf()` in the function (apart from defining the function itself); the remainder of the function is unchanged from the previous code.  The four changes make the revised code refer to the arguments to the function (`buffer` and `buflen`) instead of the variable `str` and its size in `main()`.

Note that it would be simple to use the less repetitive code in this function.  You'd change the same lines at the top of the function in the same way, and leave the rest unchanged — and the revised `main()` wouldn't be any the wiser about the change in the mechanics.

Sample run:

```
$ ./splitit
Whole string: <<(I) 44like22 .cookies. ,This, /is\ ?tricky?>>
Fragment[ 0] = (
Fragment[ 1] = I
Fragment[ 2] = )
Fragment[ 3] = 44
Fragment[ 4] = like
Fragment[ 5] = 22
Fragment[ 6] = .
Fragment[ 7] = cookies
Fragment[ 8] = .
Fragment[ 9] = ,
Fragment[10] = This
Fragment[11] = ,
Fragment[12] = /
Fragment[13] = is
Fragment[14] = \
Fragment[15] = ?
Fragment[16] = tricky
Fragment[17] = ?
Californian(*) Avocados--a joyous fruit--are "wonderful!" to eat.
Whole string: <<Californian(*) Avocados--a joyous fruit--are "wonderful!" to eat.
>>
Fragment[ 0] = Californian
Fragment[ 1] = (*)
Fragment[ 2] = Avocados
Fragment[ 3] = --
Fragment[ 4] = a
Fragment[ 5] = joyous
Fragment[ 6] = fruit
Fragment[ 7] = --
Fragment[ 8] = are
Fragment[ 9] = "
Fragment[10] = wonderful
Fragment[11] = !"
Fragment[12] = to
Fragment[13] = eat
Fragment[14] = .
$
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what I'm wrong when I tried to modify it? I would like to reuse it every time I run fgets on a file to grab a line.

Comment: Thank you for adding more info to that for fgets :).

Comment: I wanted to make a small tweak to separate `"]"` and `")"` from `";"`. So like this `"];"` and `");"`.  I didn't want to touch your code since I knew it worked. Can you explain why I had to use malloc to do this? I was quite surprised I had to use malloc and you didn't. I added what I did above.

Comment: I didn't need to use `malloc()` because I used a VLA (variable length array) instead.  In the function, I have: `char   out[2 * buflen];
    char  *ptr[buflen];`  The first (`out`) allocates enough space to store each separate character in the input string and a following null byte.  The second (`ptr`) allocates enough pointers for each separate character in the input string to be the start of a string.  Hence, I don't need to use `malloc()`.  I could use: `char *out = malloc(2 * buflen); char **ptr = malloc(bufflen * sizeof(*ptr));` with matching `free(out); free(ptr);` before the return.

Comment: I note that it isn't clear from your revised 'specification' what tokens you'd want from `if ((c = getchar()) != EOF) putchar(c);`.  In particular, the knot of parentheses after `getchar` could be 1, 2 or 3 tokens on your revised scheme.  Add a cast or abstract function declarator or two into the mix (`if (!(space = malloc(sizeof(int(*)())))) abort();`), and it would be important to understand what you want.  I think those parentheses are balanced.

Answer (score 0):

To gather ranges of inclusive or exclusive characters, use `strspn` (inclusive) or `strcspn` (exclusive; both are described [in the same link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strspn.3.html)). They both return the number of characters that fulfill the condition, and you can print this range, or process it any other way you like, and then skip that section to continue with the rest.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_range (char *input, int start, int length)
{
    putchar ('"');
    while (length--)
        putchar (input[start++]);
    printf ("\"\n");
}

void print_continuous (char *input, int start, int length)
{
    while (length--)
        putchar (input[start++]);
    printf (" ");
}

void split_string (char *input, void(*process)(char *,int,int) )
{
    int current_pos = 0, next_length;

    while (input[current_pos])
    {
        /* 1. letters? */
        next_length = strspn (input+current_pos, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
        if (next_length)
        {
            process (input, current_pos, next_length);
            current_pos += next_length;
            continue;
        }
        /* 2. digits? */
        next_length = strspn (input+current_pos, "0123456789");
        if (next_length)
        {
            process (input, current_pos, next_length);
            current_pos += next_length;
            continue;
        }
        /* 3. neither letters nor digits */
        /* first, skip spaces. These don't need processing (apparently?) */
        next_length = strspn (input+current_pos, " ");
        current_pos += next_length;

        /* then skip all others as well */
        next_length = strcspn (input+current_pos, " 0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
        if (next_length)
        {
            process (input, current_pos, next_length);
            current_pos += next_length;
        }
    }

}

int main(void)
{
    char str[] ="(I) 44like22 .cookies. ,This, /is\x5C ?tricky?";

    printf ("input: [%s]\n", str);

    split_string (str, print_range);
    split_string (str, print_continuous);


    return 0;
}
```

For convenience, I added the `process` function as a function *pointer*. That way you can easily adjust the function to do whatever you want with each fragment.

Output: the full string, one fragment per line, and separated with a single space:

```
input: [(I) 44like22 .cookies. ,This, /is\ ?tricky?]
"("
"I"
")"
"44"
"like"
"22"
"."
"cookies"
"."
","
"This"
","
"/"
"is"
"\"
"?"
"tricky"
"?"
( I ) 44 like 22 . cookies . , This , / is \ ? tricky ?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 100

void split_one(const char **p, char *out){
    if(**p){
        while(isspace(**p))
            ++*p;
        if(isalpha(**p)){
            while(isalpha(**p))
                *out++ = *(*p)++;
        } else if(isdigit(**p)){
            while(isdigit(**p))
                *out++ = *(*p)++;
        } else {
            while(**p && !isalpha(**p) && !isdigit(**p) && !isspace(**p))
                *out++ = *(*p)++;
        }
    }
    *out = '\0';
}

int main (void){
    char str[BUFFER_SIZE] = "(I) 44like22 .cookies. ,This, /is\\ ?tricky?";
    char *strings[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
    char piece[BUFFER_SIZE];
    const char *p = &str[0];

    int k = 0;

    while(*p){
        split_one(&p, piece);
        if(!*piece)
            continue;
        strings[k++] = strdup(piece);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < k; ++i){
        printf("'%s'\n", strings[i]);
        free(strings[i]);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach. At a glance, it is possible to avoid explicitly test each character with `isspace`, `isdigit` etc. by simply comparing each next character's `ctype` against the current one's. (Some characters have more than one bit set, so this needs a bit of masking.)